# login wp impossible

Tags: php, apache, linux

well i can access the sites:

```
www.foo.com and 
www.bar.com
```

but i cannot access the login - the sites are blank.

```
foo.com/wp-login.php
bar.com/wp-login.php
```

i have the following logs.

```
[Mon Jan 01 16:26:03.229924 2018] [core:notice] [pid 17589] AH00052: child pid 24869 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Jan 01 16:39:54.242584 2018] [core:notice] [pid 17589] AH00052: child pid 24872 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Jan 01 16:39:56.245833 2018] [core:notice] [pid 17589] AH00052: child pid 24870 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Jan 01 16:39:56.245959 2018] [core:notice] [pid 17589] AH00052: child pid 24871 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Jan 01 16:39:56.246014 2018] [core:notice] [pid 17589] AH00052: child pid 24873 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Jan 01 16:49:06.968278 2018] [core:notice] [pid 17589] AH00052: child pid 25032 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Jan 01 16:53:03.287697 2018] [core:notice] [pid 17589] AH00052: child pid 25034 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Jan 01 16:53:07.293645 2018] [core:notice] [pid 17589] AH00052: child pid 25039 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Jan 01 16:53:59.364044 2018] [core:notice] [pid 17589] AH00052: child pid 25106 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

in other words - the admin-area is not acessible

what can i do: should i change the wp-login.php url to /login/ 
to get it to work: so all links in registration and forgot password emails have /login/ rather than wp-login.php.

Comment: If this worked one day, try to recover the site from a backup.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a problem-causing plugin.

Look at the error.log file which will tell you the file that is causing the problem. Rename that plugin's folder (use your hosting control panel's File Manager) and retry. That should get you into the admin area. Then you can contact the plugin's support forum to figure out the fix - or just delete the plugin.

Alternately, you can rename the entire plugin folder (in wp-content) so that all plugins are disabled, then move those plugin files individually by their folders to re-enable them.

But looking at the error.log file (via your hosting cPanel or via FTP program or hosting File Manager) will help you zero in on the problem.

Comment: or .htaccess issue?

Comment: Well, possibly. But since the site was working before, then I still suspect a plugin.
Perhaps the original poster will chime in and let us know of the solution.

Answer (score -1):

@the admins: this is dilbert speaking i just have logged in.

@rick and all the others: many many thanks for all you hints. 
very interesting:  all runs in vhost on a root-server.

i have the issues on three sites on the server:

i activated an older site - which was closed - running WordPress 4.7.8 - with the theme: "Twenty Seventeen theme"
with this all works nice - and  i can access the login.

For miskate i change the url of my wordpress on settings -> general. 
In order to get more infos about what is happening i need to see the php-error-logs

to see this i have to change the wp-config.php file and add this too config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','localhost/wordpress');
define('WP_SITEURL','localhost/wordpress');
```

Then i need to restart the apache and i hope i could enter again on my admin panel. ..But everytime i u use the .../wordpress/wp-login.php i receive a 404 not found

BTW: SEE THE SESSION

```
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user mm
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary
Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 3600    3600
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  32  32
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  3600    3600
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    mm  mm
session.save_path   no value    no value
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_strict_mode Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```